# Cant ssh a virtualbox instance - Permission denied, please try again

Tags: 14.04, permissions, virtualbox, ssh

Im using ubuntu and Im trying to create a ssh connection between my ubuntu desktop and virtualbox ubuntu instance.

I have my ubuntu virtualbox instante configured with bridge, and in my ubuntu desktop Im trying to connect to my virtualbox instance like this: `sudo ssh nameofvminstance`

I enter the correct password of my vbox instance, but Im having always the same message: "Permission denied, please try again".

Do you see why this can be happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove `sudo`, just do:

```
ssh nameofvminstance
```

then enter the password.

If you do `sudo ssh nameofvminstance`, then you are basically trying to log in to the host `nameofvminstance` as `root`, if thats the case then at first you need to enter the password of your account in the host computer to get the `sudo` access and then the password of the `root` account of `nameofvminstance`.

Now if you do `ssh nameofvminstance`, its basically a short form of `ssh username@nameofvminstance` where the username in the remote computer is the same as the currently logged in user of the host machine i.e. you can use this format if both usernames are same otherwise you need to mention the username as `ssh username@nameofvminstance`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But Im having the same message without sudo! Sometimes have also this message "Permission denied (publickey,password)"

Comment: @Marby: Please check my edits..if you are not using `sudo` then whats the username you are trying to login as.. use full syntax: `ssh username@nameofvminstance` ..make sure there is an user account exists in `nameofvminstance` by that name.